# Find lines in a file that has only words in a list

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Here is file1.txt:

```
.apple .ball .cow
.apple .cow .tea .mine.nice
.mine.nice
.tea
.zebra
```

Here file2.txt

```
.apple
.mine.nice
.cow
.tea
```

Expected Result:

```
.apple .cow .tea .mine.nice
.mine.nice
.tea
```

while using following does not give expected result

```
grep -w -F -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

gives

```
.apple .ball .cow
.apple .cow .tea .mine.nice
.mine.nice
.tea
```

How to get expected result?

Comment: (Previously posted as an answer because I didn't have enough reputation.) I haven't come up with an alternative that is any simpler than the awk or sed answers here, but thought it worth explaining something. What you are trying to do is fundamentally different to what grep is designed to do, which is to find all lines that contain any matching strings. You could chain grep commands together (e.g., with pipes, |) to get all lines that contain all of the strings, but finding lines that only consist of a specific set of substrings is probably always going to require a complex regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

I would exploit GNU `AWK` `next` for this task following way, let `file1.txt` content be

```
.apple .ball .cow
.apple .cow .tea .mine.nice
.mine.nice
.tea
.zebra
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
.apple
.mine.nice
.cow
.tea
```

then

```
awk 'NR==FNR{arr[$1];next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if(!($i in arr)){next}};print}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

gives

```
.apple .cow .tea .mine.nice
.mine.nice
.tea
```

Explanation: during processing 1st file of mentioned (note that this is `file2.txt`) i.e. where number of row is equal number of row of current file (`NR==FNR`) ask about key being 1st file of array `arr`. This cause creating key in array, I do not specify any value and it is irrelevant for future. After doing that go to `next` line, i.e. do not do anything else during processing 1st file. For all but 1st line iterate over fields using `for` loop, if you encounter field which is not one of keys of array `arr` go to `next` line, after processing all fields `print` whole line as is. Note that this code *short-circuit* i.e. go to next line as soon as 1st not allowed word is detected. **Disclaimer**: I assume that `file2.txt` is holding exactly 1 word per line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for  you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '1{x;s/.*/cat file2/e;y/\n/ /;s/$/ /;x}
         s/.*/& \n&/;G
         :a;s/^(\S+ )(.*\n.*\n.*\1)/\2/;ta;s/^\n(.*)\n.*/\1/p' file1
```

The solution juggles three lines in the pattern space, two copies of the current line and the contents of file2. The first copy of the current line is matched against the strings in file2 and reduced in size until there are no more matches. If the result of the matching produces an empty line, the matches were successful and the line is printed otherwise it is discarded. The flow of processing is as follows:

Prime the hold space with the contents of file2, replace newlines by spaces and append a space for pattern matching purposes.

Double the current line, again adding a space to the first copy,separate the copies by newlines and append the hold space.

Iterate through the strings at the front of the first copy of the current line, removing it if it matches in file2.

When there are no more matches, if all that is left is the newline separating the copies then print the unadulterated copy of the current line.

Otherwise the current line did not match the strings in file2 and no output is produced for that line.

Comment: I expected that to fail if an entry  in file1.txt had a different char where `.` appears in file2.txt, e.g. it'd print `.mineXnice`, but when I tested it it didn't behave that way. Where in the script is the magic happening that's making it do a string instead of regexp comparison?

Comment: @EdMorton on the first line the contents of the file2 is stuffed into the hold space and the  newlines replaced by spaces. File2 is appended to the current line and its copy, then using back references any strings that match those in file2 are removed. If all matches are removed the current line is valid.

Comment: Ah, so it's the fact it's a backreference comparison that makes it a literal string comparison, right?

Comment: @EdMorton yes the regexp `^(\S+ )` matches all non-space characters from the start of the copy of the original current line and the `(.*\n.*\n.*\1)` refers to it in the contents of the appended file2.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept the `comm` tool (it is a really simple tool), you can do it like this.

For each line in file1.txt, you can get the words only exists in that line but not file2.txt by `comm` tool with `-2 -3` params. if the output is not empty. then print the line.

```
cat file1.txt | xargs -I {} bash -c 'if [[ -z $(comm -2 -3 <(echo {} | sed "s/\s\+/\n/g" | sort) <(sort file2.txt)) ]]; then echo {}; fi'
```